# Есть ли решение которое убирает все чекеты на странице в type="radio"

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть ли простое решение, которое убрало бы все отметки radio (приводил к первоначальному виду) при условии, что есть несколько блоков с разными id?

Решение вроде данного примера

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', false);
```

но касательно не чекбоксов, а radio.

Comment: `$('input[type="radio"]').prop('checked', false);`?

Comment: Я пробовал так,но у  меня вместе с ним пропадают список полей в чек боксах в другом поле :(

Comment: До клика http://shot.qip.ru/00tXa3-33YtCRNbD/ после клика http://shot.qip.ru/00tXa3-43YtCRNbE/

Answer (score 3):

Аналогично:

```js
$('#reset').click(function() {
  $('input[type="radio"]').prop('checked', false)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<b> <input type="radio" id="rdSelect"/> Select/Deselect </b>
<br/><br/><b> <input type="radio" id="rdSelect"/> Select/Deselect </b>
<br/><br/><b> <input type="radio" id="rdSelect"/> Select/Deselect </b>
<br/><br/><b> <input type="radio" id="rdSelect"/> Select/Deselect </b>
<br/><br/><b> <input type="radio" id="rdSelect"/> Select/Deselect </b>
<br/><br/><b> <input type="radio" id="rdSelect"/> Select/Deselect </b>
<br/><br/><b> <input type="radio" id="rdSelect"/> Select/Deselect </b>
<br/><br/><b> <input type="radio" id="rdSelect"/> Select/Deselect </b>
<br/><br/><b> <input type="radio" id="rdSelect"/> Select/Deselect </b>
<br/><br/><b> <input type="radio" id="rdSelect"/> Select/Deselect </b>
<br/><br/><b> <input type="radio" id="rdSelect"/> Select/Deselect </b>
<br/><br/><b> <input type="radio" id="rdSelect"/> Select/Deselect </b>
<br/><br/><b> <input type="radio" id="rdSelect"/> Select/Deselect </b>
<br/><br/><b> <input type="radio" id="rdSelect"/> Select/Deselect </b>
<br/><br/><b> <input type="radio" id="rdSelect"/> Select/Deselect </b>
<br/><br/><b> <input type="radio" id="rdSelect"/> Select/Deselect </b>
<br/><br/>
<button id="reset">Reset</button>
```